# Can I add multiple symptoms for one disease in the same table?

Tags: python, django

Example:

I have table named disease, and it contains four fields:

1. DiseaseId
2. DiseaseName
3. DiseaseType
4. Symptoms

As for one disease, many symptoms can be present. So, can I store as many data as needed in that one field-symptoms? How? And if I can't then what's the other solution?

Comment: Yes, use a list, like this : `"Symptoms" : ["symptom_1", "symptom_2", ..., "symptom_n"]`.

Comment: Okay...Can you please give me one example by taking 2 different disease with different no. Of symptoms

Comment: Welcome to SO: you may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can make a symptoms table and then relate it using one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Yeah...that's the one solutions but I want same table for both disease and symptoms

Comment: But then that will be redundancy of data(symptoms). And we should avoid that.

Comment: But I can provide you with 1 elegant option if u need.

Comment: Okay...give me that option

Comment: @CharmiShah Have u tried taggit and taggit_selectize? If you face any problem I can help you on team-viewer.

Comment: If I use it and face any problem I will contact you..Thanks for helping me!!

Comment: @CharmiShah, If you think my solution worked for you? You can select my answer. Thanks for cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is to use one-to-many relationship like this:

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    # insert fields

class Symptom(models.Model):
    disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, related_name='symptoms')
    # insert other fields
```

Then, you will be able to get symptoms of a diseases through `related_name`:

```
disease.symptoms.all()
```

But if you want to use one table for both of them, you can use `JSONField`:

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    symptoms = models.JSONField()
```

Then, you can create a disease like this:

```
Disease.objects.create(symptoms=['first', 'second'])
```

But, it is PostgreSQL only. So, if you are not using Postgres, you can't use it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Okay
I am using sqlite3
So its better to use 1st option